# Find url in a text file php

Tags: php, regex, replace, find

I need a php code for search and find all urls in a Text(.txt) file but the urls started from webhost

for example:

text.txt:

```
hello , thank you for order our website: http://webhost.org
your website: http://yourwebsite.com
```

the php code just showing site.com

please help me

thanks

Comment: Make the PHP to show `yourwebsite.com`. We aren't a code writing service. Kindly consider adding your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Negative Lookahead to ensure http:// is not followed by webhost

```
 (?:https?:\/\/)(?!webhost)(.*?\.(?:com|org))
```

will match anything after http:// including .com or .org unless `webhost` is found after it

Comment: Thank you but it not working and show all urls in txt file

Comment: Sorry, can't test in PHP right now, but in regex101 it only captures 'yourwebsite.com' https://regex101.com/r/zX0cH7/1